# changing states of button in tkinter by self values

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, state

I have a class GUI creating a tk window with a couple of widgets
I want the save button state to change depending on a few self's values

inside the def **init** :

```
btn_save['state']='disabled'
if self.basepath and (self.variable.get() == 0 or self.variable.get() =='1) and (self.secondOpt.get() == '0 or self.secondOpt.get() == 1):
        btn_save['state']='normal' #here I want to change the save button state
```

Main Program:

```
window = Tk()
my_gui = GUI(window)
window.mainloop()
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `after` method as follows:

```
def state_change():
'''your code here'''
if self.basepath and (self.variable.get() == 0 or self.variable.get() =='1) and (self.secondOpt.get() == '0 or self.secondOpt.get() == 1):
    btn_save['state']='normal' #here I want to change the save button state
    root.after(100, state_change) #if you want to keep changing the state of the button
root.after(100, state_change)
```

OR

use a `Button` widget to exclusively change it (something that you don't need)

Comment: so i'll need to bind it to a widget through a command or should I insert this method in a few widgets?

Comment: this can be added in the `__init__` method. make the callback method a class method. Nest the methods only if you are comfortable with it